# AngularJS - move repeating functions from controller to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm pretty new at angular JS and i'm trying to refactor my controller and want to move repeating multisort function as a service and call it back in the controller.

Can someone help me in converting this below function as a service as it has all $scope and I know it can't be used in the service or factory:

```
$scope.multiSort = function(columnName){

            if($scope.orderByField.includes(columnName)){
                if(reverseSortObj[columnName].count == 2){
                    var index = $scope.orderByField.indexOf(columnName)
                    $scope.orderByField.splice(index, 1);
                    delete reverseSortObj.columnName;
                    return;
                }
                var indexToReplace = $scope.orderByField.indexOf(columnName);
                $scope.orderByField[indexToReplace] = '-'+ columnName;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse = !reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].count ++;
            }
            else if($scope.orderByField.includes('-'+ columnName)){
                if(reverseSortObj[columnName].count == 2){
                    var index = $scope.orderByField.indexOf('-' + columnName)
                    $scope.orderByField.splice(index, 1);
                    delete reverseSortObj.columnName;
                    return;
                }
                var indexToReplace = $scope.orderByField.indexOf('-' + columnName);
                $scope.orderByField[indexToReplace] = columnName;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse = !reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].count ++;
            }
            else{
                reverseSortObj[columnName] = {};
                reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse = false;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].count = 1;
                $scope.orderByField.push(columnName);
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with your question, but why are you learning angularJS if this is getting deprecated and not maintained anymore by end of this year? Why not focus on Angular?

Comment: some company have a lot of code in angular JS it's really expensiv to do all the refact, even if he may doesn't not work in a company he can learn this tech to be able to work with this kind of company. So learning Angular JS is still a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the service and send in your parameter. The following code is untested, but you should get the idea. Send in the objects that you need and do the work. With two variables being modified, I'd recommend returning an object with orderByField and reverseSortObj as its properties since you don't necessarily want to rely on pass-by-reference. After return, you want to set the modified values to your scope or local variables.

```
'use strict';

angular.module("myApp").factory('sortService', {
    function multiSort(orderByField, reverseSortObj, columnName) {
        if(orderByField.includes(columnName)){
            if(reverseSortObj[columnName].count == 2){
                var index = orderByField.indexOf(columnName)
                orderByField.splice(index, 1);
                delete reverseSortObj.columnName;
            } else {                
                var indexToReplace = orderByField.indexOf(columnName);
                orderByField[indexToReplace] = '-'+ columnName;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse = !reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].count ++;
            }
        }
        else if(orderByField.includes('-'+ columnName)){
            if(reverseSortObj[columnName].count == 2){
                var index = orderByField.indexOf('-' + columnName)
                orderByField.splice(index, 1);
                delete reverseSortObj.columnName;                    
            } else {
                var indexToReplace = orderByField.indexOf('-' + columnName);
                orderByField[indexToReplace] = columnName;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse = !reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse;
                reverseSortObj[columnName].count ++;
            }
        } else {
            reverseSortObj[columnName] = {};
            reverseSortObj[columnName].reverse = false;
            reverseSortObj[columnName].count = 1;
            orderByField.push(columnName);                
        }
        
        return { orderByField: orderByField, reverseSortObj: reverseSortObj };
    }
        
    return {
        multiSort: multiSort
    };
});


// in controller or directive
var result = sortService.multSort($scope.orderByField, reverseSortObj, columnName);
$scope.orderByField = result.orderByField;
reverseSortObj = result.reverseSortObj;
```

Comment: Thanks you but I end up getting "Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider" 

Below is how my controller def looks:

app.controller("AvailabilityReportController",['$scope','sortService',
 function($scope, sortService ){
}

Any Idea what I'm missing?

Comment: That looks good to me. Verify you have included the sortService.js file within your index.html or bundled files.  app.controller("AvailabilityReportController",['$scope','sortService', function($scope, sortService ){ }]   Also make sure you have your ending square bracket

Comment: I was able to fix it but now I end up getting this error and I checked all the braces are correctly open and closed in sortService.js. Any idea what is this? as it's coming in the code you shared. Any help would be really appreciated i need to fix this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ym3c96vq/  Here is a JSFiddle showing a simple controller and service calling the controller. Open your Console DevTool and check the console. You said you were able to "fit it", but now end up getting "this" error but what error is now showing? Please copy and paste the error.

Comment: Also make sure the app name is correct, angular.module("myApp"). Replace "myApp" with whatever your angular.module app name is, or use app.factory('sortService', {...}). Additionally, verify your service.js file in your html or bundle config is listed above your controller.js file. Ordering may matter here.

Comment: rechecking everything in the meanwhile this is the error missed in the last comment Mentioning the error below:    

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Wb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.n._evalUrl (jquery.min.js:4) "<div class=\"main_div_view ng-scope\" ng-view=\"\" style=\"width: 110%;\" data-ng-animate=\"1\">"

Comment: The code that is pasted above was just throw together and not tested. I'd recommend you deleting everything within the multiSort function and replace it with console.log('Testing service'). This will be a quick way to verify the service has been added correctly without any additional compiler issues. Once you can get a very simple function going, go ahead and slowly add the different parts of the function back in. Test, recheck. Hopefully its something exceptionally simple that is causing your issue.

Comment: Hey! I did all the steps and update the fiddle as well and it looks good but when i run in my local i get the error: ReferenceError: columnName is not defined and when i try to define it as columnName = { }; my page loads but the sorting doesn't work :( any idea why ?

Comment: columnName = ''; Looks like columnName is a string, not an object. In the multiSort function, the first line can check to see if columName is null. If so, set to an empty string. Verify in your controller that the 3rd column is being sent in correctly.

Comment: 3rd parameter*, columnName, is being in correctly.

Comment: Hey Forgot to thank you. I really appreciate all the help I was able to figure out that part and process ahead in my app. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Also, Can you check this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jbt8aqvc/8/) please. why doesn't it work when I try to put 2 different functions inside the same factory service?

Comment: Thank you. Can you mark this as answered complete. Compare your version to mine (very minimal change, spell actually). https://jsfiddle.net/vjb0mwg7/   You need to make sure console.log is spelled correctly on your line 12. And on line 4, multiSortLevel2 not multiSortLeve2

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change the code, you can directly pass $scope to the service and get as scope.

Below is an working example, simplified on your requirement.

```js
(function(){
 var app = angular.module('App', []);
 
 app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'AppService', function($scope, AppService){
  $scope.text = 'Hello World';
  $scope.columns = ['a', 'c', 'b'];
  $scope.sorted = AppService.sort($scope);
  
  console.log($scope.sorted);
  
 }]);
 
 
 app.service('AppService', [function(){
 
 var service = {};
 
 service.sort = function(scope){
 
   return scope.columns.sort();
 }
 
 return service;
 
 }]);
 
 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I'm trying to put this function as a service in a separate file as the same function is being used again n again in all the 8 controllers. Any help on that how can I proceed?

Comment: There is a service file name AppService. You need to move your function to that. Copy paste that service code to your file and replace sort function.